# How to validate the format of a string in Ruby, while extracting the matches?

Tags: regex, ruby

## What I want

- validate that a string matches this format: `/^(#\d\s*)+$/` (`#1 #2` for instance).
- Grab all the numbers with the hash, something like `#<MatchData "1234" 1:"#1" 2:"#2">`. It doesnt have to be a MatchData object, any type of array, enumerable would work.

## My issue

When using `match`, it just matches the last occurence:

```rb
/^(#\d\s*)+$/.match "#1 #2"
# => #<MatchData "#1 #2" 1:"#2">
```

When I use scan, it "works":

```rb
"#1 #2".scan /#\d/
# => ["#1", "#2"]
```

But I dont believe I can validate the format of the string, as it would return the same for `"aaa #1 #2"`.

## The question

Can I, with only 1 method call, both validates that my string matches `/^(#\d\s*)+$/` AND grab all the instances of `#number`?

I kinda feel bad about asking this since I've been using ruby for a while now. It seems simple but I can't get that to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you may use

```
s.scan(/(?:\G(?!\A)|\A(?=(?:#\d\s*)*\z))\s*\K#\d/)
```

See the [regex demo](https://rubular.com/r/sCVRrUcZfhUw0f)

**Details**

- `(?:\G(?!\A)|\A(?=(?:#\d\s*)*\z))` - two alternatives:

  - `\G(?!\A)` - the end of the previous successful match
  - `|` - or
  - `\A(?=(?:#\d\s*)*\z)` - start of string (`\A`) that is followed with 0 or more repetitions of `#` + digit + 0+ whitespaces and then followed with the end of string
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespace chars
- `\K` - match reset operator discarding the text matched so far
- `#\d` - a `#` char and then a digit

In short: the start of string position is matched first, but only if the string to the right (i.e. the whole string) matches the pattern you want. Since that check is performed with a lookahead, the regex index stays where it was, and then matching occurs all the time ONLY after a valid match thanks to the `\G` operator (it matches the start of string or end of previous match, so `(?!\A)` is used to subtract the start string position).

[Ruby demo](https://ideone.com/jVluVv):

```
rx = /(?:\G(?!\A)|\A(?=(?:#\d\s*)*\z))\s*\K#\d/
p "#1 #2".scan(rx)
# => ["#1", "#2"]
p "#1 NO #2".scan(rx)
# => []
```

Comment: Ok, you nailed it. But at least the answer wasn't so obvious as to make me feel bad for not coming up with it ;) In practice, I almost feel like using a simple match + scan if matches more readable tho.

Comment: @Robin In real life, the 2 step approach is preferable since it is much more readable. Since Ruby does not expose each group capture stack (as in .NET or Python PyPi `regex` module, you can't but resort to such workarounds, or 2-step validation+extracing approach.

Comment: `\G`, which I haven't been able to find in Ruby docs, appears to be quite useful. I confess I still don't fully understand it's effect (but will work on it).

Comment: @CarySwoveland See [*Continuing at The End of The Previous Match*](https://www.regular-expressions.info/continue.html) and [Beginning of String or End of Previous Match: \G](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-anchors.html#G). Basically, it helps anchor the matches to the start of the string or make regex match only consecutive matches. Together with a lookahead, `\G` makes a perfect solution to match some pattern multiple times within some delimiting substrings, if they are different. If the delimiters are the same, it won't work (e.g. between double quotation marks).

Comment: Thanks, Wiktor. The Tarzan and Jane example was particularly helpful.

Answer (score 1):

```
def doit(str)
  r = /\A#{"(#\\d)\\s*"*str.count('#')}\z/      
  str.match(r)&.captures
end

doit "#1#2 #3 "    #=> ["#1", "#2", "#3"]
doit " #1#2 #3 "   #=> nil
```

Notice the regular expressions depend only on the number of instances of the character `'#'` in the string. As that number is three in both examples the respective regular expressions are equal, namely:

```
/\A(#\d)\s*(#\d)\s*(#\d)\s*\z/
```

This regular expression was constructed as follows.

```
str = "#1#2 #3 "
n = str.count('#')
  #=> 3
s = "(#\\d)\\s*"*n
  #=> "(#\\d)\\s*(#\\d)\\s*(#\\d)\\s*" 
/\A#{s}\z/ 
  #=> /\A(#\d)\s*(#\d)\s*(#\d)\s*\z/
```

The regular expression reads, "match the beginning of the string followed by three identical capture groups, each optionally followed by spaces, followed by the end of the string. The regular expression therefore both tests the validity of the string and extracts the desired matches in the capture groups.

The [safe navigation operator](http://mitrev.net/ruby/2015/11/13/the-operator-in-ruby/), `&` is needed in the event that there is no match (`match` returns `nil`).

A comment by the OP refers to a generalisation of the question in which the pound character (`'#'`) is optional. That can be dealt with by modifying the regular expression as follows.

```
def doit(str)
  r = /\A#{"(?:#?(\\d)(?=#|\\s+|\\z)\\s*)"*str.count('0123456789')}\z/
  str.match(r)&.captures
end

doit "1 2 #3 "     #=> ["1", "2", "3"] 
doit "1 2 #3 "     #=> ["1", "2", "3"] 
doit "1#2"         #=> ["1", "2"] 
doit " #1 2 #3 "   #=> nil   
doit "#1 2# 3 "    #=> nil 
doit " #1 23 #3 "  #=> nil
```

For strings containing three digits the regular expression is:

```
/\A(?:#?(\d)(?=#|\s+|\z)\s*)(?:#?(\d)(?=#|\s+|\z)\s*)(?:#?(\d)(?=#|\s+|\z)\s*)\z/
```

While it is true that this regular expression can potentially be quite long, that does not necessarily mean that it would be relatively inefficient, as the lookaheads are quite localized.

Comment: That's an interesting way to go about it, thanks. I did simplify my question for SO tho, and my input could be strings like `#1, 2, #3`, or `1 2 #3` etc so it's not the best approach for my case. Thanks anyway.

Comment: We can't be mind readers; neither is @Wiktor's answer applicable to your "real" problem. I modified mine to deal with the more general case you give. I also simplified my answer to your original question. Incidentally, be careful when simplifying your real problems; it may not be possible to modify solutions to the simplified version to address the actual problem. Mainly, I found both versions of the question interesting, providing good exercise for the little grey cells.

Comment: Sure, you can't be mind readers, but I was hoping for an answer that would work not just for my specific case but every case where I needed to match a string and extract all the matched data. So I didn't think I needed to provide my exact use case. Turns out, it's a bit harder than expected.